# jquery pngfix not working

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, png-24

I have a site with a lot of bg png images. css like this:

```
div#carousel ul#slides li.monitor{
  background:url(../images/monitor.png) no-repeat center top;   
  position:relative;
}
```

and I have jquery and pngfix included as such:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");
</script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.pngFix.pack.js"></script>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).pngFix(); 
    ...
})
```

yet still my pngs do not show up in IE7, IE8, etc. Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery.pngfix.js is only for IE 5.5 and 6.0. Internet Explorer 7 and 8 supported 24-bit transparent PNGs natively and do not require a fix. However, there are some specific formats of PNG that IE7/IE8 *don't* support. If you go with the standard 24-bit alpha transparency, then you'll be fine. But some other variants... not always.

Convert them to 24-bit if they aren't already, and confirm that IE is loading them properly over the network (no 404 errors, etc.).

Comment: If you are still having problem with the images after converting them, can you post the specific PNGs for us?

Comment: hmm. I'm not sure I'm that proficient with PNG exporting. Generally, I'm exporting from Photoshop with default PNG 24-bit settings (transparency selected). I'll upload a sample to my initial post. And thanks!

Comment: as a note - some of the other 24-bit pngs are working. Is there a limitation on the file size of these???

Comment: ack. forgot to mention this is in a jquery carousel (using cycle() ) if that matters...

Comment: Those should be the correct types of PNGs. In that case, its my guess that it's not a PNG/transparency display problem, but a JavaScript compatibility problem. Are there any errors in the console? Do those images load correctly when set on plain HTML/CSS not created by the Carousel library?

Comment: yes. i believe that's the issue. it hadn't occurred to me that this was the problem, but I found this post: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-plugin-and-png-transparency-in-ie8-and-ie7. I suppose my options are to use gifs. oh well!!! thanks for your help - got me on the right track!